# In xamarin forms android project doesn't read id from xml file

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms

Hello I want to create splash screen in xamarin forms but the activity in the android project can't read the lottie Id from xml file using the command:  var animationView = FindViewById(Android.Resource.Id.animation);

xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<com.airbnb.lottie.LottieAnimationView
    android:id="@+id/animation"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:lottie_fileName="load.json"
    app:lottie_autoPlay="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />
     <Button android:id="@+id/nom"/>
  </LinearLayout>
```

the Activity:

```
   namespace theXam.Droid
   {
   [Activity(Label = "Splash" , Theme = "@style/Theme.Splash",
    MainLauncher = true)]

public class Splash : Activity  , Animator.IAnimatorListener
{
    public void OnAnimationCancel(Animator animation)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public void OnAnimationEnd(Animator animation)
    {
        StartActivity(new Intent(Application.Context, typeof(MainActivity)));
    }

    public void OnAnimationRepeat(Animator animation)
    {
    }

    public void OnAnimationStart(Animator animation)
    {
    }

    protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);

        //***for splash
        SetContentView(Resource.Layout.SplashActivity);
```

the error is in this line:

```
       var animationView =       FindViewById<LottieAnimationView>(Android.Resource.Id.animation);
         animationView.AddAnimatorListener(this);


        // Create your application here
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Please  add `xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"` in your Linearlayout like following code.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">



<com.airbnb.lottie.LottieAnimationView
    android:id="@+id/animation_view"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:lottie_fileName="load.json"
    app:lottie_loop="false"
    app:lottie_autoPlay="true" 
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    ></com.airbnb.lottie.LottieAnimationView>


</LinearLayout>
```

There is my demo, you could refer to it.
https://github.com/851265601/theXam

Comment: @sos Do you have any updates? If the reply help to you, please mark the reply as answer.